# How to handle Database connection inside TimerTask

Tags: java

I have a Timer Task scheduled for every  4 minutes , whose task is to insert/update values into mysql table .

My question is that , do i need to make the DBConnection for every iteration(run method)

Some part of my code

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        TimerTask task = new RunMeTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000,60000);
    }
}

public class RunMeTask extends TimerTask 
{
PreparedStatement inserpstmt = null;
Connection conn = null;
String insertsql = "";
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            inserpstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertsql);
            inserpstmt.setString(1, symbol);
            inserpstmt.setString(2, date);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know , thanks in advance

Comment: The short answer is yes, you have to make a DBConnection each and every time you want to create, read, update, or delete database information.

Answer (score 0):

The best pattern would be to reuse connections. If your TimerTask is within a Container make use of that infrastructure and you should have database connection pooling and may even enjoy the benefit of container managed transactions.

If this does not work out for you, do not try to pool connections yourself. There are implementations out there, e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/